# How to change the image size in new Media Uploader (ie use medium vs thumbnail)

Tags: uploads, media-library, media-modal

Is it possible to change the image size of the thumbnails in the new media uploader?

For example images are currently displayed using the "thumbnail" image crop size and I would like them to be the "medium" image crop size.

Comment: Just to clarify...are you talking about changing the display of the Media stuff on the backend or images being used in the content somewhere?

Comment: For within the new Media Uploader only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that I'm [interpreting your Question correctly](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)...

The thumbnails displayed in the new Media Uploader are already the `medium` sized ones, being constrained on the fly.

> [image: media uploader inspector]

So, it's a matter of applying some CSS styling to increase their size. Maybe other style adjustments are necessary, this is just a proof of concept.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'style_thumbnails_wpse_81677' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'style_thumbnails_wpse_81677' );

function style_thumbnails_wpse_81677()
{
    $thumb_width  = get_option( 'medium_size_w' );
    $thumb_height = get_option( 'medium_size_h' );

    echo "
    <style type='text/css'>
        .details.attachment, .attachement, .attachment.save-ready {
            width:{$thumb_width}px !important;
        }
        .attachment-preview, .attachment-preview .thumbnail {
            width: {$thumb_width}px !important;
            height: {$thumb_height}px !important;
        }
        .portrait .thumbnail img, .landscape .thumbnail img {
            max-width: {$thumb_width}px !important;
            max-height: {$thumb_height}px !important;
        }
    </style>
    ";
}
```

**Result:**

> [image: bigger thumbs in new media uploader]

Comment: how do you enable the "attachment display settings", they don't appear on my site

Answer (score 0):

```
//wp-admin.css

.media-item .pinkynail {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 2px 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

change max width and height to the size you want