# Is it possible to change image size used for preview thumnail in Add Media popup

Tags: images, media, thumbnails

I has cleaned up my media items by removing all the medium and large size from upload dir. So the medium size now could not be found.

Currently the Media library popup (when click Add media) uses medium for default and because of my medium size is lost, it uses full size instead, and it causes a slow load time. How can I change the display size of preview image in Media Library from medium to thumbnail.

Related: 
[How to change the image size in new Media Uploader (ie use medium vs thumbnail)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81677/how-to-change-the-image-size-in-new-media-uploader-ie-use-medium-vs-thumbnail)

Answer (score -1):

From fire bug, you can check where the image is rendered and then you can do it by simple styling.
sample_style.css

```
div img {
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Using css just resize display dimension but not actual (natural) size, and my case can not resolve.

Comment: you mean to display the images in their actual sizes? I mean in the sizes they were uploaded?

Comment: My Media Libary now uses fullsize as actual size for each preview image, because I have removed all medium item. Thus the page is very very slow and heavy load. So I want to change the actual size to thumbnail.

Comment: ah, then simple way is to add those images again so that it will store images in medium size as well

Comment: I just thought of it, but I still want to ask first as if there's another way.